# form display results under questions + array?

Tags: javascript, html

I am having trouble displaying the results on my form under the questions. I thought I had it right. Also I need to create an Array that will hold the answers, which it will randomly pick one, doesnt have to go by the answers. I can't figure out how to display the results on the same page (I have looked and had no luck) Could anyone help me

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<?php
include "menu.html"
?>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Form</title>
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script>
function checkForm(){

    var chk = true;
    var Name = document.getElementById("txt");
    var methd=  document.getElementById("method");
    var rad1=   document.getElementById("radM");
    var sel=    document.getElementById("selM");
    var necro = document.getElementById("a");
    var guard = document.getElementById("b");
    var ele = document.getElementById("c");
    var shatter = document.getElementById("imp");

    var cor = 0;        
        Name.style.backgroundColor="#fff";
        methd.setAttribute("style", "display:none");
        rad1.setAttribute("style", "display:none");
        sel.setAttribute("style", "display:none");      

    if (Name.value==''){            
        Name.style.backgroundColor = "red";
        methd.setAttribute("style", "display:inline");
        chk = false;
    }
    if ((necro.checked==false) && (guard.checked==false) && (ele.checked==false)){

            rad1.setAttribute("style", "display:inline");       
}
    if (shatter.value==0){
        selM.setAttribute("style", "display:inline");
}
    if (chk==false){
        document.getElementById("error").setAttribute("style", "display:inline");

} else {                         
        if (Name.value=="no"){
            document.getElementById(txt).innerHTML += 'No';}            
        if (Name.value=="yes"){
            document.getElementById(txt).innerHTML += 'Yes';}
        if (ele.checked == true){
            document.getElementById(c).innerHTML += 'Elementalist';}                    
        if (necro.checked == true){
            document.getElementById(a) += 'Necromancer';}                               
        if (guard.checked == true){
            document.getElementById(b) +='Guardian';}                                       
        if (shatter.value==1){
            document.getElementById(imp) += 'Shatter';  
        }
        if (shatter.value==2){
            document.getElementById(imp) += 'Sunless';  
        }           
        if (shatter.value==3){
            document.getElementById(imp) += 'Claw'; 
        }           
        style.display = "inline";
        innerHTML = "<span>You chose " + imp + txt + " correct!</span>";            
    }           
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="page">  
<article>
    <div id="error" class="error"></div>
      <h1>What Guild Wars 2 Profession Are You</h1>

        <div class="cssTable" style="margin-top:-25px;">
        <form method="post" action="thankyou.php"  >
          <table>
          <tr><td colspan="3"></td></tr>
            <tr>
            <td><div align="right">In Guild Wars 2 Do You Like To Do Damage?    </div>        </td><td width="217"><input id="txt" name="txt" type="text" size="25">    <br/></td><td><div id="method" style="display:none"><img  height="25px" src="purple.png"  ></div></td><br/></tr>
            <tr>
                <td><div align="right">What Best Describes You?</div></td><td>
                <input id="a" type="radio" name = "group1" value="A">Healer</input><br/>
                <input id="b" type="radio" name = "group1" value="B">One With The Elements</input><br/>
                <input id="c" type="radio" name = "group1" value="C">Darkness</input>

                </td><td><div id="radM" style="display:none"><img  height="25px"     src="purple.png"></div></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>What One Skill Would You Like To Have?</td>
                <td>
                <select id="imp"><option value="0" selected="true">Pick A     Skill</option>
                <option value="1">Stealth</option>
                <option value="2">Summon Illusions</option>
                <option value="3">Great With A Bow and Arrow</option></select>
                </td><td><div id="selM" style="display:none"><img  height="25px" src="purple.png"></div></td>
                </tr>
                <tr><td colspan="3" align="right"><input type="button" class="styled-button-7" value="Send" onclick="checkForm()"  /><span id="grde" style="padding-left:25px">    </span></td></tr></table></form></div></article> 
</main></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you really intend to post to thankyou.php or is it your intent for this to be strictly client-side?

Comment: Yes... Not intended for this question, its a separate page it is going to after its all done. All my stuff goes to that page. So yes it is suppose to be on there. Im going to do that at the very end

Answer (score 0):

I moved your call to `checkForm()` from an `onclick` on a button to the `onsubmit` of the form, and started returning `chk` from `checkForm()`. You should go through your `checkForm()` function and start making it work field by field. There are properties that you're trying to access incorrectly.

You can see it at:
http://jsbin.com/homeq/1/